# boost.python: Calling function of a base class from Python

Tags: python, inheritance, boost, boost-python

I have a module with a C++ class exposed:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(){}
    void foo(){
        //...
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module){
    class_<MyClass>("MyClass", init<>())
        .def("foo", &MyClass::foo)
        ;
}
```

In Python, I create a class that is derived from this class.

```
from my_module import *

class Derived(MyClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo()

d = Derived()
```

I get the error:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    MyClass.foo(Derived)
did not match C++ signature:
    foo(class MyClass {lvalue})
```

I expected to be able to call a function defined in the base class from the derived class. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to call `MyClass.__init__(self)` before calling `foo`; otherwise `foo` isn't getting a `MyClass` instance. Bonus points for using [super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods).